# Remove a specific user from a Django Channels group?

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a couple of Django Channels groups that I use to send various messages to the client with.

Can I remove a specific user from one of these groups, using only the ID of the user that I want to remove?

Another potential option would be to force disconnect the user's connection using just their ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this in the end by storing each channel name (self.channel_name) on channel connection, and removing them on disconnect. These are then tied to a Django user object.

Now, if I want to remove a user from a group, I can just loop over all stored channel names tied to a user object, and run group_discard.

Comment: Don't suppose you can post an example?

Comment: please share a link or an example of how we can work with "group_discard"

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to save the **user's channel_name** to their model

and we assume that you had the **group_name of channels** too

then you can use **group_discard** for deleting user from group like this:

```
group_name = 'name_of_channels_group'
user = User.objects.get(id=id)
channel_name = user.channel_name
async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(group_name, channel_name)
```

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html?highlight=group_send#groups

Answer (score 0):

I have thought couple a days about this problem and have an idea how this can be implemented, but can't test it currently. You should try to change your `receive() method` like this:

```
async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        users_to_kick = text_data_json['kick']

        # you should inspect scope['user'] cuz I am not sure in what place
        # user's id is placed, but there is 'user' object.
        if self.scope['user']['id'] in list(map(int, users_to_kick)):
            await self.close()
        else:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'some_method',
                    'message': message
                 }
             )
```

You have to have *Authorisation* system enabled, you can't kick Anonymous users. And you have to send from Front-End a list of users which you want to kick.

Answer (score -1):

You need to prevent connect based on `scope['user']` in consumer `connect` method like this:

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        id_cannot_connect = 1
        if self.scope['user'] == id_cannot_connect:
            await self.close()
        else:
            await self.accept()
```

If you want to make lists of users allowed to connect to specific groups you'll need to store groups and group users in your database and use it the same way in `connect` method like above.

edit: You can discard user's channel from the group with [group_discard](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_layer_spec.html?highlight=group_discard) in `receive_json` where you still have access to `self.scope['user']` to filter needed users.

Comment: but "preventing user to connect" is not the same that "disconnect user from the channel". What if user is already on the channel?

Comment: You can discard user's channel from the group with [group_discard](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_layer_spec.html?highlight=group_discard) in `receive_json` where you still have access to `self.scope['user']` to filter needed users.

Comment: I'm looking to remove a user from a group outside of a channel, for example in another users channel.

Say User A submits an action via channels to kick User B out of a chat, I'd need to physically kick User B out of the group server side so they stop receiving all messages.

Comment: @JamesFoley I use `group_discard(group_name, self.channel_name)` in my chat app when User A wants to leave a group (chat room) and he stops receiving messages from said group.

Comment: Yes, but that's User A removing himself from a group. I want to remove another user from a group...